# How to use redis PUBLISH/SUBSCRIBE with nodejs to notify clients when data values change?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I'm writing an event-driven publish/subscribe application with NodeJS and Redis. I need an example of how to notify web clients when the data values in Redis change.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

## OLD only use a reference

### Dependencies

uses [express](http://expressjs.com/), [socket.io](http://socket.io), [node_redis](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis) and last but not least the [sample code](http://www.mediafire.com/?94iz516qwar10ew) from media fire.

### Install node.js+npm(as non root)

First you should(if you have not done this yet) install [node.js+npm in 30 seconds](https://gist.github.com/579814#file_node_and_npm_in_30_seconds.sh) (the right way because you should **NOT** run npm as **root**):

```
echo 'export PATH=$HOME/local/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
. ~/.bashrc
mkdir ~/local
mkdir ~/node-latest-install
cd ~/node-latest-install
curl http://nodejs.org/dist/node-latest.tar.gz | tar xz --strip-components=1
./configure --prefix=~/local
make install # ok, fine, this step probably takes more than 30 seconds...
curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

### Install dependencies

After you installed node+npm you should install dependencies by issuing:

```
npm install express
npm install socket.io
npm install hiredis redis # hiredis to use c binding for redis => FAST :)
```

### Download sample

You can download complete sample from [mediafire](http://www.mediafire.com/?94iz516qwar10ew).

### Unzip package

```
unzip pbsb.zip # can also do via graphical interface if you prefer.
```

### What's inside zip

**./app.js**

```
const PORT = 3000;
const HOST = 'localhost';

var express = require('express');

var app = module.exports = express.createServer();

app.use(express.staticProvider(__dirname + '/public'));

const redis = require('redis');
const client = redis.createClient();

const io = require('socket.io');

if (!module.parent) {
    app.listen(PORT, HOST);
    console.log("Express server listening on port %d", app.address().port)

    const socket  = io.listen(app);

    socket.on('connection', function(client) {
        const subscribe = redis.createClient();
        subscribe.subscribe('pubsub'); //    listen to messages from channel pubsub

        subscribe.on("message", function(channel, message) {
            client.send(message);
        });

        client.on('message', function(msg) {
        });

        client.on('disconnect', function() {
            subscribe.quit();
        });
    });
}
```

**./public/index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>PubSub</title>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="/javascripts/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script>    
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var socket = new io.Socket('localhost', {port: 3000, rememberTransport: false/*, transports: ['xhr-polling']*/});
            var content = $('#content');

            socket.on('connect', function() {
            });

            socket.on('message', function(message){
                content.prepend(message + '<br />');
            }) ;

            socket.on('disconnect', function() {
                console.log('disconnected');
                content.html("<b>Disconnected!</b>");
            });

            socket.connect();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

### Start server

```
cd pbsb    
node app.js
```

### Start browser

Best if you start google chrome(because of websockets support, but not necessary). Visit `http://localhost:3000` to see sample(in the beginning you don't see anything but `PubSub` as title).

But on `publish` to channel `pubsub` you should see a message. Below we publish `"Hello world!"` to the browser.

### From ./redis-cli

```
publish pubsub "Hello world!"
```

Comment: why do you need `const client = redis.createClient()` in the root of app.js?

Comment: you don't need to use const at all. var could be used as well and maybe I should have instead because const is only available in the newer javascript engines. Furthermore this line ensures we are connected to redis server which we use in this example.

Comment: @Alfred I tried your example and it seems that it never goes in the socket.on('connection', function(client) { block. I tried to print something there and never does. if I remove this part I can normally publish and see the message in the console. Also when I run pubsub.js the following are printed on the console: Express server listening on port3000
   info  - socket.io started
Do you maybe have an idea of what might be wrong in my case?

Comment: The sample is very old so not up to date with latest socket.io/express modules and maybe even node.js. I would try to update code. There is also another huge problem with this code that it opens another redis connection for each connected user. That should only be on instead. I have to work first, but after that I try to update the code.

Comment: @Alfred I think that I managed to fixed it. Not sure if my code is good (it's my second day that I work with node.js). I 've put it on github(I wanted to play a little bit with it as well) https://github.com/dinostheo/redis_pbsb_node.js_socket.io_Hello_world

Comment: Very good. I still think there is room for some improvements which when I have time I will put online. But right now I am really working hard :$.

Comment: @Imme22009 Sorry but I haven't done anything on this since then
https://github.com/dinostheo/redis_node_pbsb

Comment: I think subscribe.on should be outside the socket.on('connection') block to avoid multiple subscribes/

Comment: Why did you emphasize not to install npm as root?

Answer (score 29):

here's a simplified example without as many dependencies.
You do still need to `npm install hiredis redis`

The node JavaScript:

```
var redis = require("redis"),
    client = redis.createClient();

client.subscribe("pubsub");
client.on("message", function(channel, message){
  console.log(channel + ": " + message);
});
```

...put that in a pubsub.js file and run `node pubsub.js`

in redis-cli:

```
redis> publish pubsub "Hello Wonky!"
(integer) 1
```

which should display: `pubsub: Hello Wonky!` in the terminal running node!
Congrats!

*Additional 4/23/2013:* I also want to make note that when a client subscribes to a pub/sub channel it goes into subscriber mode and is limited to subscriber commands. You'll just need to create additional instances of redis clients. `client1 = redis.createClient(), client2 = redis.createClient()` so one can be in subscriber mode and the other can issue regular DB commands.

Comment: Here when we add data to the redis, should I run publish pubsub to get notification of insert?

Comment: @IshaS if that's what you need to do, yes.  You should also look into transactions if you need to run multiple commands atomically: http://redis.io/commands/exec

Comment: @nak This worked like charm in one GO :) Some users may need to install 'double-ended-queue' if not installed already.

Comment: It also worth to mention that if you want to use wildcards, for example, subscribe to `pubsub/*` just add `p` to the example: replace `subscibe` with `psubscribe` and `message` with `pmessage`.

Answer (score 8):

#### *Complete* Redis Pub/Sub Example (*Real-time Chat* using Hapi.js & Socket.io)

We were trying to understand Redis Publish/Subscribe ("*Pub/Sub*") and all the existing examples were either outdated, too simple or had no tests.
So we wrote a ***Complete* Real-time Chat using Hapi.js + Socket.io + Redis Pub/Sub Example with End-to-End Tests**!

> [https://github.com/dwyl/hapi-socketio-***redis-chat-example***](https://github.com/dwyl/hapi-socketio-redis-chat-example)

The Pub/Sub component is only a few lines of node.js code:
https://github.com/dwyl/hapi-socketio-redis-chat-example/blob/master/lib/chat.js#L33-L40

Rather than pasting it here (*without any context*) we *encourage* you to checkout/try the *example*.

We built it using [Hapi.js](https://github.com/nelsonic/learn-hapi) but the `chat.js` file is *de-coupled* from Hapi and can *easily* be used with a *basic* **node.js http server** or **express** (etc.)

Comment: do you have this example with express?

Comment: @Gixty we wrote the example using Hapi.js *because* all the other examples out there use Express.js ... as mentioned in the post, its trivial to port it to any other Node.js framework (simply pass in the express app/listener to the chat.js init code) and it works exactly the same. p.s: if you are new to Hapi.js see: https://github.com/nelsonic/learn-hapi

Answer (score 4):

Handle redis errors to stop nodejs from exiting. You can do this by writing;

```
subcribe.on("error", function(){
  //Deal with error
})
```

I think you get the exception because you are using the same client which is subscribed to publish messages. Create a separate client for publishing messages and that could solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [acani-node on GitHub](https://github.com/acani/acani-node), especially the file [acani-node-server.js](https://github.com/acani/acani-node/blob/master/acani-node-server.js). If these links are broken, look for acani-chat-server among [acani's GitHub public repositories](https://github.com/acani).

Comment: Wow, this looks pretty sweet!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get this working with socket.io 0.7 *AND* an external webserver you need to change (besides the staticProvider -> static issue):

a) provide the *domain name* instead of localhost (i.e. var socket = io.connect('http://my.domain.com:3000'); ) in the index.html

b) change HOST in app.js (i.e. const HOST = 'my.domain.com';  )

c) and add *sockets* in line 37 of app.js (i.e. 'socket.sockets.on('connection', function(client) { …' )

Answer (score 1):

Update to the code:

> staticProvider

now renamed to

> static

see [migration guide](http://expressjs.com/migrate.html)

Answer (score 0):

according to [@alex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441798/how-to-use-redis-publish-subscribe-with-nodejs-by-event-driven/4446424#4446424) solution. if you have an error like this one as per [@tyler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441798/how-to-use-redis-publish-subscribe-with-nodejs-by-event-driven/5628546#5628546) mention:

```
node.js:134
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error'

event on first tick ^ Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - ECONNREFUSED, Connection refused at Socket.
```

then you need to install [Redis](http://redis.io/download) first. check this out:

> http://redis.io/download