# How do I detect client disconnected inside a net.CreateServer?

Tags: node.js

Good day,

I was playing with the example found here on SO: [PHP Socket Server vs node.js: Web Chat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573186/php-socket-server-vs-node-js-web-chat).

Using gMUD (a telnet-like client) to connect to my server, I can't seem to be able to detect when the client disconnect from the server.

Here is the two events I'm using:

```
socket.on('end', function() {
    console.log('end');
});

socket.on('error', function() {
    console.log('error');
});
```

To be honest, I thought the error event could do it. Is there any other events I'm actually missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it. It was abvious:

```
socket.on('close', function() {
    //Do something
});
```