# What are good message queue options for nodejs?

Tags: node.js, message-queue

Looking to use a message queue in a small web app I'm building with node.js. I looked at resque but not sure that's appropriate. The goal is to push notifications to clients based on backend and other client actions with socketio. I could do this with just socketio but I thought maybe a proper message queue would make this cleaner and I wouldn't have to reinvent the wheel.

What are the options out there?

Comment: Not sure, but this seems like something node would do well by itself!

Comment: You're probably aware of this already, but there's one listed on the Modules page: https://github.com/ry/node/wiki/modules#message-queue . I guess there's always the cost of your own development time to consider.

Comment: @ TK-421 and Bjorn Tipling That's indeed something node can do itself, as long as you only have one node process. An external solution such as Redis is needed if you have different processes for different parts of your application (i.e. webserver, auth provider, notif center etc.). And of course you can then connect with non node processes as well.

Comment: Examples using Node AMQ and Rabbit MQ (Producer) https://gist.github.com/DarcInc/9641557 and (Consumer) https://gist.github.com/DarcInc/9641582

Comment: In case you need an in-memory queue you can consider this [rxjs-based solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46539032/1555615)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

you could use [redis](http://redis.io) with the lightning fast [node_redis](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis) client. It even has built-in [pubsub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441798/how-to-use-redis-publish-subscribe-with-nodejs-by-event-driven/4446424#4446424) semantics.

Comment: I recommend using a good queueing module on top of redis, just like RSMQ, which seems to be pretty simple. https://www.npmjs.com/package/rsmq

Comment: if you just want the power of messaging without the technical concerns creeping in then you can try https://node-ts.github.io/bus/

Answer (score 14):

You could use the node [STOMP client](https://github.com/kates/node-stomp).  This would let you integrate with a variety of message queues including:

- ActiveMQ
- RabbitMQ
- HornetQ

I haven't used this library before, so I can't vouch for its quality.  But STOMP is a pretty simple protocol so I suspect you can hack it into submission if necessary.

Another option is to use [beanstalkd with node](https://github.com/benlund/node-beanstalk-client).  beanstalkd is a very fast "task queue" written in C that is very good if you don't need the feature flexibility of the brokers listed above.

Answer (score 12):

Shameless plug: I'm working on [Bokeh](https://github.com/nullobject/bokeh): a simple, scalable and blazing-fast task queue built on ZeroMQ. It supports pluggable data stores for persisting tasks, currently in-memory, Redis and Riak are supported. Check it out.

Answer (score 11):

Here's a couple of recommendations I can make:

[node-amqp](https://github.com/postwait/node-amqp): A RabbitMQ client that I have successfully used in combination with Socket.IO to make a real-time multi-player game and chat application amongst other things. Seems reliable enough.

[zeromq.node](https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node): If you want to go down the non-brokered route this might be worth a look. More work to implement functionality but your more likely to get lower latency and higher throughput.

Comment: +1 on using ZeroMQ. After a lot of research and time spent tinkering with beanstalkd, RabbitMQ, BeeQueue, Bull and Kue, ZeroMQ ended up being the best experience for me, especially for lightweight projects powered by workers. It's lightning fast and the documentation is top notch. It also has the added benefit of not clogging up your Redis server with a large amount of calls.

Comment: `zeromq.node` now maintained here: [zeromq.js](https://github.com/zeromq/zeromq.js)

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at [node-busmq](http://github.com/capriza/node-busmq) - it's a production grade, highly available and scalable message bus backed by redis.

I wrote this module for our global cloud and it's currently deployed in our production environment in several datacenters around the world. It supports named queues, peer-to-peer communication, guaranteed delivery and federation.

For more information on why we created this module you can read this blog post: [All Aboard The Message Bus](http://www.capriza.com/blog/all-aboard-the-message-bus/)

Answer (score 7):

I recommend trying [Kestrel](https://github.com/robey/kestrel), it's fast and simple as Beanstalk but supports fanout queues. Speaks memcached. It's built using Scala and used at Twitter.

Comment: It is worth noting that Kestrel is no longer in active development.

Answer (score 7):

[kue](https://github.com/learnboost/kue) is the only message queue you would ever need

Comment: except kue is not well maintained, has several issues and not a single test !

Comment: Also, it's a job queue - not a message queue

Comment: It has several issues and is not fit for production

Comment: Using `bull` was more straightforward to me. With `kue` I was lost in the documentation.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to have a look at

[Redis Simple Message Queue for Node.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rsmq)

Which uses Redis and offers most features of Amazons SQS.

Comment: While RSMQ is nice and has been working for me in production once, be aware that it's using Lua scripts in Redis and will not work with Redis cluster/sentinel setup

Answer (score 3):

Look at [node-queue-lib](https://github.com/AndyGrom/node-queue-lib). Perhaps it is enough that you.
It support node.js and browsers. Has two delivery strategies: broadcast and round-robin.
Only javascript.

Quick example:

```
var Queue = require('node-queue-lib/queue.core');

var queue = new Queue('Queue name', 'broadcast');

// subscribe on 'Queue name' messages
queue.subscribe(function (err, subscriber) {
    subscriber.on('error', function(err){
        //
    });
    subscriber.on('data', function (data, accept) {
        console.log(data);
        accept(); // accept process message
    });
});

// publish message
queue.publish('test');
```

Answer (score 3):

How about Azure ServiceBus? It supports nodejs.

Answer (score 2):

I used KUE with socketIO like you described.
I stored the socketID with the job and could then retreive it in the Job Complete..
KUE is based on redis and has [good examples on github](https://github.com/learnboost/kue)

something like this....

> ```
> jobs.process('YourQueuedJob',10, function(job, done){
>     doTheJob(job, done);
> });
>
>
> function doTheJob(job, done){
>     var socket = io.sockets.sockets[job.data.socketId];
>     try {
>         socket.emit('news', { status : 'completed' , task : job.data.task });
>     } catch(err){
>         io.sockets.emit('news', { status : 'fail' , task : job.data.task , socketId: job.data.socketId});
>     }
>     job.complete();
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to check out ewd-qoper8: https://github.com/robtweed/ewd-qoper8