# Node.JS based ESB

Tags: node.js, esb

Does anybody know of a ESB written in Node.JS. It seems like node would be great for this. Probably note something on the scale of IBM DataPower, I only need the following features for now:

- Content based routing
- AAA
- Logging
- Monitoring

I could start writing one myself, but I was wondering if there might be an existing project to build upon.

Thanks

Comment: Because I did not know what ESB meant, [Enterprise Service Bus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_service_bus)

Comment: how about this one? https://github.com/hookio/hook.io

Comment: Hi, did you eventually create one yourself? I have had some thoughts about this myself recently

Comment: @AlanFoster hi, have you found anything interesting in regards to a JS esb?

Comment: @Nikos No, unfortunately I abandoned such a project in favour of writing IntelliJ tooling for Apache Camel, an existing Java integration framework

Comment: @AlanFoster ok, I noticed SWARM ESB, I've done a lot of work with mule but I write so much JS it would be nice to use it in ESB projects. However I don't think it would scale as well as multithreaded Java and how it would compare with stability.

Answer (score 3):

Try [@node-ts/bus](https://node-ts.github.io/bus/) is a true service bus written in Typescript for Node.

As a service bus, it has both message handling and workflows/sags built in.

Message brokers can be swapped in without having to change code, and currently it supports SQS and RabbitMQ. New brokers can be used by [implementing a transport](https://node-ts.github.io/bus/packages/bus-core/src/transport/).

Under the hood, the bus takes care of all the implementation and complexity of topic and queue subscriptions, publications, routing etc. It also leverages [@node-ts/logger](https://github.com/node-ts/logger) that lets you use the in-built logger, or you can swap it out for your own.

Finally the service bus was designed to be compatible with [@node-ts/ddd](https://github.com/node-ts/ddd), which is a Domain Driven Design library for Typescript/Node.

Hopefully these are enough to get you started

**Update**: Docs have moved to https://node-ts.gitbook.io/bus/, and v1 now works without inversify

Answer (score 2):

I've not tried any so I can't comment on the specifics you want.

The only project that refers to ESB that I can find is [ESBX on Google](http://code.google.com/p/esbx/) but it doesn't seem to have got anywhere, at least as yet - you could try contacting the author.

On the other hand, there *are* a number of Node projects with Message Queues which might form the heart of what you want:

- [Websocket.MQ](https://github.com/networkimprov/websocket.MQ)
- There are a couple based on RabbitMQ - see the [Message Queue list on Node's Wiki](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-message-queue)
- The Key/Value store [Redis](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-db-nosql-redis) has also been mention on [another Stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700935/what-are-good-message-queue-options-for-nodejs) & there is an MQ project based on this as well [QDis](https://github.com/gflarity/qdis)

Certainly, the content based routing and logging is routine for Node systems. Monitoring is also trivial in Node.

Regards, Julian.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [SwarmESB](https://github.com/salboaie/SwarmESB), I haven't tried it yet, but it looks pretty interesting.

Comment: Sorry, I ended up not getting the project that lead me to look at it in the first place. :(