# Nodejs, dedicated server, cpu intensive task

Tags: node.js, multithreading, performance, web-services, server

I am doing a cpu intensive task on a dedicated server running on nodejs using the following procedure. Wondering if this is the correct approach (steps and approach as a whole) -

(Note - Time of completion of cpu intensive task is not important as long as it just gets done)

1. Create a nodejs web server (WS) and another nodejs server for cpu intensive tasks (CPS) on different ports on the same machine
2. WS sends cpu intensive task to CPS via a localhost http request
3. CPS gets blocked, performs each task sequentially. WS is not directly affected by CPS being blocked (I am assuming this!)

**Question1.** What will happen if CPS has a huge queue which keeps on growing, due to requests sent by WS?  
**Question2.** Is this a bad way of doing CPU intensive work? What will be a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer1**. If CPS keeps on enqueueing requests, at some point (at a very very large request queue), [heap size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap) of application will exceed the OS limit -> CPS will be shut down losing all the enqueued requests. Think of this scenario like a DDOS attack on CPS!

**Answer2**. If queue is expected to become large, it is recommended that a task queue (like [kue](https://github.com/Automattic/kue)) / message queue like [Redis Simple Messaging Queue (rsmq)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rsmq) be used.

I went with simple HTTP at this point of time as my load is not that huge. I may update this answer later (when my server load increases).

(Some sources come from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700935/what-are-good-message-queue-options-for-nodejs) on Stackoverflow)