# How can I implement a queue using Rxjs?

Tags: rxjs

With promises, it's really easy to implement a queue to prevent for example multiple HTTP requests from running in parallel:

```
class Runner {
  private promise;
  constructor(http) {
    this.promise = q.resolve();
  }
  getUrl() {
    return this.promise = this.promise.then(() => http.get('http://someurl'))
  }
}

var runner = new Runner(http);

var lastPromise;
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  lastPromise = runner.getUrl();
}

lastPromise.then(() => console.log("job's done!");
```

I can't figure out how to do this in Rxjs tho. If I try something similar to the above, all previous HTTP calls get repeated when I add a request because it just adds to the stream and reruns the whole thing.

I read something about a queue scheduler, but that doesn't seem to exist (anymore)?

Comment: Just use [`concat`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-concat).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use concat like @cartant suggested:

```js
const urlQueue = Observable.fromPromise(http.get('http://someurl'))
  .concat(Observable.fromPromise(http.get('http://someurl')))
  .concat(Observable.fromPromise(http.get('http://someurl')));
```

But you would need to construct such a stream before subscribing and letting the queue handle it. Also; `fromPromise` is still eager so your promises will all start running directly when you invoke above code. To solve this you would need to use [`Defer()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-defer):

```js
const urls = [
  'http://someurl',
  'http://someurl',
  'http://someurl',
];

const queue = urls
  .map(url => Observable.defer(() => http.get(url))
  .reduce((acc, curr) => acc.concat(curr));
```

This approach uses the native array `map` to convert the urls to Observables and then uses [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to concat them all together into one big stream.

A better solution would be to get your url's into a stream and then use [`mergeMap`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-mergeMap) with a concurrency appended to it:

```js
const urls = [
  'http://someurl',
  'http://someurl',
  'http://someurl',
];

const queuedGets = Observable.from(urls)
  .mergeMap(url => http.get(url), null, 1);
```

This will result in the urls being retrieved one by one after the previous one has completed but you still need to have all urls ready before starting. Depending on your usecase this might suffice. Note that a `mergeMap` with concurrency set to `1` is the equivalent of just using `concatMap`

The last part of the puzzle maybe is that you need to push new urls into your queue in your own tempo. To do so you would need a [Subject](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#subject)

> A Subject is like an Observable, but can multicast to many Observers. Subjects are like EventEmitters: they maintain a registry of many listeners.

```js
class HttpGetQueue {
  const queue = new Subject();

  constructor() {
    public results = queue
      .mergeMap(url => http.get(url), null, 1);
  }

  addToQueue(url) {
    queue.next(url);
  }
}

const instance = new HttpGetQueue();
instance.results.subscribe(res => console.log('got res: ' + res);
instance.addToQueue('http://someurl');
instance.addToQueue('http://someurl');
instance.addToQueue('http://someurl');
```

Comment: `mergeMap`'s third argument is news to me! The docs are really light on the details of `concurrent`; I suggest the more specialized [`concatMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/concatmap.html).

Comment: I totally agree about the documentation being sub-par. And you are right; mergeMap with concurrency `1` == `concatMap`

Comment: @MarkvanStraten thanks for this example. The last part with the concatMap seems to be what I'm looking for. Just one thing that I'm missing now - I'd like to be able to subscribe to the addToQueue step, but it's not returning anything. How'd I approach that?

Comment: @BartvandenBurg depends on what you want `addToQueue` to return. You could have a fake result `Observable.empty()`. You could also return the result of your queued action by generating a pseudo-unique id and subscribing to the response you link to this id but this might get very confusion fast due to multiple subscriptions or no subscribers resulting in the queue stopping/starting or duplicate behaviour.

Comment: Ok, I ended up doing the following: `addToQueue(url) { var s = new Subject(); queue.next([url, subject]); return s.asObservable(); }` and the queue: `public results = queue.mergeMap(input => http.get(input[0]).do(res => { input[1].next(res); input[1].complete(); }).catch(e => { input[1].error(e); return null; }`. Seems to do the trick. Does it make sense?

Comment: `.mergeMap` is no longer available in this way. It would need to be used with `pipe`, ex: `queue.pipe(mergeMap(url => http.get(url), 1)`.

Comment: I was wondering why my promises were executed right away in my queue... `defer` operator was what I was missing 

Answer (score 1):

This is more simple:

```
private messageQueue = new Subject<string>();

private initQueue() {
    this.messageQueue.pipe(
        concatMap((msg: string) => this.doSomethingWithItAsync(msg))
    ).subscribe((res) => {
        console.log("message processed, result: " + res);
    });
}

doSomethingWithItAsync(msg: string): Promise<any> {
    // your async logic
}

addMessageToQueueAndProcess(msg: string) {
    this.messageQueue.next(msg);
}
```

**That's it!**

If you want more control and use the complete interface, just build s. th. like this:

```
runMessageQueue() {
    this.messageQueue.next("msg1");
    this.messageQueue.next("msg2");
    this.messageQueue.complete();
}
```

In the subscription use a full observer:

```
.subscribe({
    complete: () => {
        console.log("complete");
    },
    next: (val) => {
        console.log(val);
    }
});
```