# NodeJS Queues and Transactions

Tags: node.js

I have a requirement where I have to read a message from a queue and send it to 3 different queues..
I have to do this in the transaction, in case one of the queue fails, all queues must roll back.
I must admit, I am a totally newbie to the Node.Js and  I dont have a clue how to even start here.

Basically

```
Read from Source Queue
Start Transaction


* Write it to queue 1
* Write to Queue 2

End Transaction.

If transaction fails, then log and retry.
```

I could not find a resource that can point me to this.. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You'll need a message queuing system with rollbacks and commits. Which MQ system do you use? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Some suggestions.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700935/what-are-good-message-queue-options-for-nodejs