# socket.io has xss vulnerability? How to solve this?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I believe socket.io has a XSS vulnerability and I am wondering how to solve this.

See my post about [pubsub redis with socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441798/how-to-use-redis-publish-subscribe-with-nodejs-by-event-driven/4446424#4446424) which has a/the XSS hole.

from redis-cli when you do:

```
publish pubsub "<script>alert('Hello world!');</script>"
```

You will see an alert dialog with `Hello world!` which is **BAD...**

To solve this I copied the following snippet from visionmedia's jade library and wondering if this is enough?

```
/**
 * Escape the given string of `html`.
 *
 * @param {String} html
 * @return {String}
 * @api private
 */

function sanitize(html){
    return String(html)
        .replace(/&(?!\w+;)/g, '&amp;')
        .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
        .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
        .replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
}
```

Is this enough or am I missing something? Maybe even inside socket.js to solve the problem?

Comment: What "xss vulnerability" do you think it has?

Comment: updated my question to the snippet on another topic which has this vulnerability.

Comment: Displaying untrusted data verbatim is an XSS vulnerability. There's nothing about this particular to socket.io.

Comment: But socket.io can (and should escape it) or am I wrong?

Comment: Considering this question is already the second result on Google for "socket.io escape" (and the top result for "socket.io xss"), I would guess that it doesn't. And why should it? If it automatically escaped stuff for you, that would make it unnecessarily difficult to use it to fetch HTML from trusted sources. If you want to escape stuff, do it yourself.

Comment: So then my next question is how would you escape it properly using node.js/javascript?

Comment: lol down-voting without explaining why is really bullsh*t.

Comment: @Alfred: Maybe people can't stand the thought of magic quotes in node :D - awww. that's actually a scary thought. would be so UGLY!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [node-validator](https://github.com/chriso/node-validator) library which provides sanitization methods for XSS.