# Executing javascript code with node.js

Tags: javascript, linux, compiler-construction, ubuntu, node.js

I'm trying to execute a javascript code with node.js, and I get always two errors saying :

.port 1 is not active

.port 2 is not active

This my javascript code :

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8124, "127.0.0.1");
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8124/');
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: By the way I'm under `ubuntu` and I use `node myscript.js` to compile.

Comment: very strange it should work. I would reinstall node correctly using this previous example from me. I think it explains it thoroughly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441798/how-to-use-redis-publish-subscribe-with-nodejs-by-event-driven/4446424#4446424

Comment: try `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1` Sounds like there's an issue with how your router is set up and the like

Comment: Always getting the same problem, even after changing 127.0.0.1 by localhost

Comment: @Raynos that example just works for me. `$node -v 0.2.6` as it should!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have anything else listening on 8124 already?

```
netstat -an|grep :8124
```