# How does redis pub/sub data interact with mobile app on CentOS 7

Tags: php, mysql, qt, redis, architecture

I made a stock-like app, which received data from outside then publish them to clients. I want to use redis as cache to save 7 days’ data and MySQL to save all data.
But I have wondered how to deal with subscribe data interaction is effective? I have used remote connection from mobile app to redis server, but the server is infected with mining virus. So it seems like unsafe. 
What about php api? I don’t use pub/sub but use ‘get’ once a second use php api? It seems ineffective.
Java is difficult to me. I could use Qt to write a server, but it seems like poor performance on high concurrency.
I am confused.

Comment: This seems to ask various questions and is too broad (and possibly will create various opinionated answers).  An obvious first point is to sort out the redis server!

Comment: @NigelRen Thank you for your reply. Yes. But the main question is that I don’t know which method to take to receive the subscribe from redis server.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449911/creating-a-redis-listener-possible-in-php help?