# Redis Pub/Sub not displaying published message in client using redis-cli

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redis, socket.io

Hello guys i'm having a problem in redis pub/sub because my client does not show the message i've published in redis-cli. I used the codes found here in stackoverflow and i made some modification. [Here is the link and code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441798/how-to-use-redis-publish-subscribe-with-nodejs-to-notify-clients-when-data-value) I hope you can help me, my goal is to publish the message to the client index.html using redis publish in redis-cli. I've done this before but i can't make it work again. Thanks in advance guys.

**Here is my client index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>PubSub</title>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="/javascripts/socket.js"></script> -->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script>
            var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');    
            var content = $('#content');

            socket.on('connect', function() {
            });

            socket.on('message', function (message){
                content.prepend(message + '<br />');
            }) ;

            socket.on('disconnect', function() {
                console.log('disconnected');
                content.html("<b>Disconnected!</b>");
            });

            socket.connect();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Here is my server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var redis = require('redis');
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(app);
var socket = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var publish = redis.createClient();

app.listen(3000);
    console.log("Express server listening on port 3000")

    app.get('/', function (req,res) {
        res.sendfile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
    });

socket.on('connection', function (client) {
        var subscribe = redis.createClient();
        subscribe.subscribe('pubsub');

        subscribe.on("message", function (channel, message) {
            publish.send(message);
        });

        publish.on('message', function (msg) {
        });

        publish.on('disconnect', function() {
            subscribe.quit();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Redis will not send data to connected clients for you. You must instruct Socket.IO to emit data:

```
subscribe.on("message", function (channel, message) {
  socket.emit('message', message);
});
```

Comment: Are you receiving messages through the subscribe or publish connection? Please clarify.

Comment: I'm receiveing messages throught the subscribe sir, my html client does'nt show it. Is there any other problem in my codes? Thanks sir.

Comment: Can you verify that the Redis subscribe is actually receiving any data?

Comment: I've subscribed through cli and published throuhg the cli but the message doesn't show in the client page.

Comment: There's already `<div id="content"></div>` in my client sir line 9. :(

Comment: i did not get any error sir. would you like to see my code?
[Here](http://sdrv.ms/15DgCRS) is the client and the server.

Comment: Change `publish.send(message);` to `socket.emit('message', message);`.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: oh. thanks. i also moved out some methods outside the io.sockets.emit