# Making a node.js process controlled from outside

Tags: node.js

I have a node.js app that is intended to be running all the time. Is a core process that does some specific work for each of our clients.

Today, that app is feed with the clients data by a config (json) file on startup, every time we need to add/remove a client or change a client data, we edit the json and kill/restart the app.

I came with the idea of building another node.js app that should work as a cli to send instructions to the main app, I don't know where to start, is there a solution already for this?
I tought of using sockets to connect the app with the cli, but I feel it overkill.
What's the propper way of controlling a node.js app from another node.js app?

I know this question may be vague and leaves space for discussions and opinions, but I don't know where to start looking for, all my searches give me express.js or forever/pm2 articles.

Answer (score 0):

You could try storing your data in a REDIS DB and subscribing to changes from the node applications. So, you could update the redis and the configuration changes trigger automatically from within node application

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441798/how-to-use-redis-publish-subscribe-with-nodejs-to-notify-clients-when-data-value)

Another method is to emit global events from your CLI and have your apps listen to and update their code as required.